# Upload Files to Google Drive from HTML form and save url to google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-drive-api

I am totally new to this stuff and get quite nothing of it.
I used some tutorials to write this, but I don't know how to get the link to the uploaded document in the google sheet.

This is the Apps Script code:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


// App Script function to save data to sheet
function saveData(data) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);

}



function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1NWq9CoBxzYumYQzTlCjLMS95Y6G2NY6X');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
 var uploadURL = file.getUrl();
  
}
```

And here the HTML code in: `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
        <h1>Custom HTML Forms to Google Sheet</h1>
      <br>
      <div id="form">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-data" id="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-data" id="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Age">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-data" id="Age">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Company">Company</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-data" id="Company">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Mob">Mob</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-data" id="Mob">
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="file" name="myFile">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="send_data()" id="submitBtn" value="Upload Files">Submit</button>
          
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Optional if you want to give a completion feedback! -->
      <div id="completion-msg" style="display: none;">
        Thank you for completing this form!
        <label id="resp"></label>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',
      function send_data(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
        var form_data = document.getElementsByClassName("form-data"); //retrieve filled form data
        var i;
        var data = [];
        for(i=0; i<form_data.length; i++){
          data.push(form_data[i].value);
        }
        
        
        google.script.run.saveData(data); // send to google app script
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none"; // make form invisible
        document.getElementById("completion-msg").style.display = "block"; // Optional if you want to give a completion feedback!
      })
   function onSuccess(data){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "File Uploaded to the path " +data;
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

It is totally ok, if you say that there is no way to change this code into something that works, but please say how I could solve it elsewise.
I would really appreciate it, if you help me. Thanks!

Comment: At a quick glace I see you have 2 ''doGet'' functions. How do you know which on is being executed?

Comment: I don't. I used two tutorials and combined them together. Because of that there a two "doGET" functions. Which of them should I delete?

Comment: You should have only one, pick one.

Comment: I did it, but it's still not working :/